# Sending php mail, adding country code

Tags: php, email

I add to country code input area but country code not included when sending mail. When you fill in your phone number, it looks like the picture in the picture 1 but I want you to look like the picture 2. How do I edit this in php mailer? The codes index.php and mail.php are below. (I corrected the picture by checking the item in order to be an example) If you need JS Code
http://allinoneinvest.com/landing/intlTelInput.js

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

index.php phone input code

```
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" id="container_phone"> 
<label for="phone" class="main lp-form-label" id="label_phone">Phone&nbsp;*</label><input type="tel" id="mobile-number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" name="phone" class="text form_elem_phone" required> 
</div>
```

mail.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { 
  $isimsoyisim = $_POST['your_name']; 
    $email = $_POST['your_email']; 
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
require("class.phpmailer.php"); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = "mailhost";  
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->SetLanguage("tr", "phpmailer/language"); 
$mail->CharSet  ="utf-8"; 
$mail->Username = "mail"; 
$mail->Password = "mailpwd";
$mail->SetFrom("$email", "$isimsoyisim"); 
$mail->AddReplyTo("$email", "$isimsoyisim"); 
$mail->AddAddress("email"); 
$mail->Subject = "Landing Page - $isimsoyisim"; 
$mail->Body = "<strong>Message:</strong><br />$message <br /><br /><strong>Mail:</strong> $email<br /><br /><strong>Phone:</strong> $phone<br /><br /><br /><br /> This message was sent from the landing page";
if(!$mail->Send()){ 
        echo "Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    } else { 
        $gittiMesaji = "Dear $isimsoyisim Your Message Sent"; 
    } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Both of  your image links return a 403 error so it's really not possible to know what you are asking.

Comment: @Dave I edit link please check again

Comment: Too much JS to look through. If it isn't actually modifying the DOM to update the input data you probably need to look for something that does. You could also do what it does in PHP after you have retrieved the form value.

Comment: This seems a bit unclear in what you want (or rather, what you need the JS or PHP to do).